# Template Field image based on Id

Tags: asp.net

In my Template field i want use image like below

```
 <a href="#" 
         id="lnkAssetTypeIndicator" 
         title="View/Edit Asset Details" 
         onclick="return LoadAssetDetails('<%# Eval("AssetId") %>', 0)"><%# (Eval("AssetTypeIndicator").ToString() != "1" ? "<img border='0' **src='Images/AssetType_' + '<%# Eval("myId")%> + .png'>" : "")%**>
 </a>
```

How can i get Image ?
Can any one help me?

Comment: its easier to wrap the logic of showing an image based on some boolean condition via a function.

Answer (score 0):

You were real close. To reduce clutter, I am showing only the image, not the hyperlink:

```
<%# Eval("AssetTypeIndicator").ToString() != "1" ? ("<img border='0' src='Images/AssetType_'" + Eval("myId") + ".png'>") : "" %>
```

Comment: Hi Jhon Thanks for your reply but it is not showing any image

Comment: and when you View Source, there is no <img> tag?

Comment: Actually I am assigning this image to Gridview TemplateField.

Comment: I mean when you view the HTML Source of the web page, is there no <img> tag? If not, you could try replacing the empty string with something such as `"no img"` just to make sure something is happening in this field.